# retain more than 1 pid so I can kill the processes later

Tags: bash, scripting

I am starting multiple process with a script something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

./gradlew services:service1:bootRun > /dev/null &

cd "./services/service2"

../../gradlew bootRun > /dev/null &
```

The problem is I have no idea how to stop these services without getting the process id from `lsof`.

I am starting more than 1 service.

What I want is an easy way to kill both processes at a later date without manually having to find the process ids.

I am starting 2 services which makes it more complicated.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: So, what you don't know is how to use variables in bash? Or how to kill processes?

Comment: I don't know how to easily kill the processes after they are running without using something like `lsof`.  I'd like the script to produce a command I can run to stop the processes if that is possible

Comment: `command & job1=$!` launches `command` in the background as a child process and stores its PID in bash variable `job1`. Later on, to kill the child process, just `kill -9 $job1`.

Comment: yes but how can I access the variables after the script has ran

Comment: Ah, you do not want to kill the processes from their parent process (your script)? You should consider editing your question and making it a bit clearer.

Comment: I thought it has been closed

Comment: there seems a stampede to shut questions down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156674/discussion-between-renaud-pacalet-and-dagda1).

Answer (score 0):

In the shell you can get the background job pid with `$!`.

```
$ sleep 60 &
[1] 23067
$ pid=$!
$ echo $pid
23067
$ ps p $pid u
USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      23067  0.0  0.0  11436   684 pts/3    S    22:20   0:00 sleep 60
$
```

Comment: I have updated the question, I have more than 1 pid

Comment: You can create a function to collect the pid and store in an array. And everytime you execute a command, you can call that function.
i=0
collectPid()
{
pid=$!
pidArray[$i]=$pid 
i=\`expr $i +1 \`
}